# Connecting Android to php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Good day.I have a problem connecting to mysql.But when I use the internet I can connect.I tried using 10.0.2.2/test.php and also tried ip/test.php and it does not work.I also allowed my firewall for apache for private and public.But I cannot connect still.

Any ideas.

Tell me if I should include the code because it works when I connect online.

here is the json object online:

```
{
"emp_info": [{
    "employee name": "Adam",
    "employee no": "101700"
}, {
    "employee name": "John",
    "employee no": "101701"
}, {
    "employee name": "Paul",
    "employee no": "101702"
}, {
    "employee name": "Mark",
    "employee no": "101703"
}, {
    "employee name": "Donald",
    "employee no": "101704"
}, {
    "employee name": "Brain",
    "employee no": "101705"
}, {
    "employee name": "Kevin",
    "employee no": "101706"
}]
}
```

here is the json object locally.

```
{
 "emp_info": [{
     "employee name": "john",
     "employee no": "132323"
 }, {
     "employee name": "jones",
     "employee no": "223232"
 }, {
     "employee name": "sam",
     "employee no": "3232323"
 }]
 }
```

Thanks in advanced.

*update
When I enter 10.0.2.2/test.php it says unable to access network.I can only access my php on the browser by using localhost:81/test.php

Comment: try `10.0.2.2:81/test.php`

Comment: Sorry I figured it out.localhost = 10.0.2.2.So I was also suppose to add :81 after the 10.0.2.2.

Comment: you are right.Sorry for a lame question.have been trying for hours.

Comment: you test your app on witch device? in genymotion address is 10.0.3.2